# numpy "TypeError: ufunc 'bitwise_and' not supported for the input types" when using a dynamically created boolean mask

Tags: python, numpy

In numpy, if I have an array of floats, dynamically create a boolean mask of where this array equals a particular value and do a bitwise AND with a boolean array, I get an error:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.array([1.0, 2.0, 3.0])
>>> a == 2.0 & b

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: ufunc 'bitwise_and' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe'
```

If I save the result of the comparison to a variable and carry out the bitwise AND however, it works:

```
>>> c = a == 2.0
>>> c & b
array([False,  True, False], dtype=bool)
```

The objects created seem the same in each case though:

```
>>> type(a == 2.0)
<type 'numpy.ndarray'>
>>> (a == 2.0).dtype
dtype('bool')
>>> type(c)
<type 'numpy.ndarray'>
>>> c.dtype
dtype('bool')
```

Why the difference?

Comment: try `np.bitwise_and(a==2.0,b)`

Answer (score 68, accepted):

`&` has higher [precedence](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence) than `==`, so the expression

```
a == 2.0 & b
```

is the same as

```
a == (2.0 & b)
```

You get the error because bitwise `and` is not defined for a floating point scalar and a boolean array.

Add parentheses to get what you expected:

```
(a == 2.0) & b
```

Answer (score 5):

you should try to convert your array to int

```
a = np.array([0,0,1])
# error bitwise

a = a.astype(int)
# working
```

Comment: although this may be helpful to some, it does not address the OP's actual issue, which as the accepted answer points out is operator precedence.