# Bitwise AND between hexadecimal arrays Numpy

Tags: python, numpy, bitwise-and

I would like to perform a Bitwise AND operation between two hexadecimal numpy arrays. However, NumPy does not seem to allow this operation between these arrays.

```py
a = np.array(['0x2a75210031157', '0x2a75210031157', '0x2a75210031157',
'0x100a588288688', '0x2a75210031157', '0x480066940820',
'0x2a75210031157', '0x100a588288688', '0x2a75210031157',
'0x100a588288688', '0x100a588288688', '0x480066940820',
'0x2a75210031157', '0x800006000', '0x800006000'])

b = np.array(['0x2a75210031157', '0x2a75210031157', '0x480066940820',
'0x100a588288688', '0x480066940820', '0x100a588288688', 
'0x400000', '0x480066940820', '0x100001000000', 
'0x480066940820', '0x480066940820', '0x100a588288688', 
'0x2a75210031157', '0x480066940820', '0x480066940820'])

results = a & b
results2 = np.bitwise_and(a,b)
```

```py
>>> a & b
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: ufunc 'bitwise_and' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''

>>> np.bitwise_and(a,b)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: ufunc 'bitwise_and' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''
```

Do you have any suggestions for doing this efficiently?

Comment: You can check this answer: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50656307/numpy-typeerror-ufunc-bitwise-and-not-supported-for-the-input-types-when-us](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50656307/numpy-typeerror-ufunc-bitwise-and-not-supported-for-the-input-types-when-us).

Comment: Are you sure you want to use the strings such as `'0x2a75210031157'` and not the integer values such as `0x2a75210031157`?

Comment: @Charalarg The discussion faces another problem.

Comment: @RobinGertenbach Can you show me an example? It could be a solution for this problem

Comment: You're currently defining two arrays with strings containing the text `'0x2a75210031157'` etc. If you remove the quotes around all the hex values it will store the actual values you are supplying.

Comment: Could be done for integer values. However, I might get some hex values that might exceed the maximum number that the format Int64 can represent. In this case, the types of the NumPy arrays are automatically set to Float64. This type of representation doesn't allow me to perform Bitwise AND.  For this reason, I would like to directly perform Bitwise AND on hexadecimal numbers.