# TypeError: ufunc 'bitwise_and' not supported for the input types - supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I do not understand why even if I put as type float, the code does not match the 2 arrays.

```
      def alfa_1(array1):                 
>         return (np.array(array1) >= 0)
>     
>     def alfa_2(array2,array3):                 
>         return (np.array(array2)>np.array(array3) & np.array(array2[1:])<np.array(array3[1:]))
>     
>      entry_rules = (alfa_1(df_indicators2['12 26 9'].astype('float'))) & 
>                    (alfa_2(df_indicators2['12 26 9'].astype('float'),df_indicators2['12 26 9'].astype('float')))
>
```

TypeError: ufunc 'bitwise_and' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''

Comment: Does this answer your question? [numpy "TypeError: ufunc 'bitwise\_and' not supported for the input types" when using a dynamically created boolean mask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50656307/numpy-typeerror-ufunc-bitwise-and-not-supported-for-the-input-types-when-us)

Comment: bonding /w a mask, I try to do also with my arrays. thanks for sharing

Comment: What is this `&` supposed to do with floats?  It's a logical operator, intended to work with boolean values.  `int` can be converted to boolean, `float` can't.

Comment: But wait, I see a `&` in two places.  Which raised this error.  Where's the traceback?  I'm tempted to close this for insufficient debugging details.  Also, without a [mcve] we can't run the code to see for ourselves.